# how to find the maximum of every subset of a set with O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, max, big-o

I’m having trouble with this question.

- Let `X` be a set of `n` keys
- Let `S` be a set of `m` subsets of `X`
- Find a way to find the maximum key of every subset in `S` with `O(n log n)` comparisons.

I know I can find maximum with quick sort by `O(n)` and binary sort by `O(log n)`, but I’m unsure of how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: m might be as large as 2^n, so how do you expect O(n log n) time? Perhaps problem formulation is not clear enough.

Comment: How are the subsets described ?

Comment: You sentence about the sorts does not make sense.

Comment: I just want to find a way in O(n log n) comparisons

Comment: Don't disregard the comments. As stated your question can't be answered. My downvote.

Comment: You really need to give an example and more information. If m is 2^n, this is impossible. The time bounds must include m in some way, or you need to specify the constraints on m.

Answer (score 1):

If a subset is defined by the enumeration of its elements, the largest element is obtained in time proportional to the number of elements and this is optimal.

For `m` subsets, the total work is the total number of elements, `Σni`, which is still optimal.

---

If a subset is specified by a binary mask of length `n`, you can't avoid `O(nm)` operations.

Comment: I just want to find a way in O(n log n) comparisons

Answer (score 1):

> - Let X be a set of n keys
> - Let S be a set of m subsets of X
> - Find the maximum of every subset in S with O(n log n) comparisons.

**Solution :**

- Construct a `Max-Heap` for each of the `m` subsets of X.
- Use `Heap-Sort` on each of the `m` `Max-Heaps` to find the Maximum of each of the `m` subsets of X.
- The number of comparisons in a `Heap-Sort` is `O(n log n)`.
- So, to `Max-Heapify` `m` sets, and to find the maximum of each subset (the root of each `Max-Heap`), the total number of comparisons would be `O(mn log n)`, but if `m` is a constant, we can approximate it to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: With this approach, just skip making the heaps! For each of the m subsets, find its max with a linear search in O(n). Loop that over m sets, that's O(mn).

Comment: Yes, but the goal is to have a time complexity of O(n logn). Hence this approach!

Comment: Except that you have O(mn log n), not O(n log n), and mn < mn log n for all m, n > 1, so mn is also O(mn log n). But most importantly, if your algorithm can trivially be made faster, I see no value in doing additional unnecessary computation just to put that log n into the complexity.